# How to use .toJSON() on an ice candidate in webrtc is javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, webrtc

In Javascript, I'm trying to send ice candidates via websockets (json).

I started out with this [sample](https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/blob/master/s/webrtc-from-chat/chatclient.js).

Before I use candidate.toJSON() and/or JSON.stringify() the candidate looks something like this:

```
address: "192.168.1.2"
candidate: "candidate:149645548 1 udp 1685987071 192.168.1.2 50697 typ srflx raddr 192.168.8.162 rport 50697 generation 0 ufrag o8rk network-id 1 network-cost 10"
component: "rtp"
foundation: "149645548"
port: 50697
priority: 1685987071
protocol: "udp"
relatedAddress: "192.168.8.162"
relatedPort: 50697
sdpMLineIndex: 1
sdpMid: "1"
tcpType: ""
type: "srflx"
usernameFragment: "o8rk"
__proto__: RTCIceCandidate
```

After I use .toJSON like recommended [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidate/toJSON), the it looks like this:

```
candidate: "candidate:149645548 1 udp 1685987071 192.168.1.2 50697 typ srflx raddr 192.168.8.162 rport 50697 generation 0 ufrag o8rk network-id 1 network-cost 10"
sdpMLineIndex: 1
sdpMid: "1"
__proto__: Object
```

As you can see, many properties are missing. On top of that, when I try to run "toString()" like that same link suggests, that method does not exist. When i try to JSON.parse, I get an "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

I think the problem is that this has **proto** or because of its type? But I can't seem to get much further then that.

Any help to jsonify it and send it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is intentional, see [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcicecandidate-tojson).
The additional properties are encoded in the candidate string already, so if you do this on the remote end:

```
new RTCIceCandidate({candidate: "candidate:149645548 1 udp 1685987071 192.168.1.2 50697 typ srflx raddr 192.168.8.162 rport 50697 generation 0 ufrag o8rk network-id 1 network-cost 10", sdpMid: 0})
```

the properties will be restored.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that in a bit and let you know.

Comment: That worked. Now I just need to solve this error: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Error processing ICE candidate